# Use jQuery as a dependency without loading jQuery with RequireJS?

Tags: jquery, dependencies, requirejs

Consider the following page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script data-main="app" src="require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i use jQuery as a dependency for RequireJS modules when it's not loaded with RequireJS? I know [jQuery exposes itself](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/861a45b8fffc2073baa9f62b0648f395f0695f3e/src/exports.js) as a global AMD module, so i should be able to add it as a dependency, but i'm not quite sure how to.

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
require(['jquery'], function() {
    console.log('success')
});
```

And if jQuery has not yet finished loading, it should wait for it to complete, and then continue. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load jQuery second, RequireJS first. Run your main module when both are loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        require(["app"], function(app){
            app.runMe()
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery will NOT register itself as AMD module if it does not see `define.amd` floating around. The only way to make it register itself properly is to load RequireJS before jQuery.

Comment: Not really working for me. Here's what i've got: http://pastebin.com/MwGvAd7L I'm getting a mismatch error. I read the doc but didn't really give me much. I can't even do `require('init')`, i get the same error. Any ideas? This sounds like the solution i need, i just need to get it working. *Edit:* I should also mention it spits out the entire jquery source in the console.

Comment: Turns out what was logged in the console wasn't jQuery, but BlockUI (whatever that is). If i remove BlockUI it works, but BlockUI is included by a plugin on my site so i can't remove it. Not really sure what to do here. Ideas?

Comment: Found this in the bottom of BlockUI: `if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery) {
  define(['jquery'], setup);
 } else {
  setup(jQuery);
 }` Why does it override jQuery with `setup`?

Comment: BlockUI likely does **NOT** redefine jQuery. It **depends** and **asks** for jquery likely to extend it.   Also, I don't see where you load jQuery in the [PasteBin example you provided](http://pastebin.com/MwGvAd7L)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, hope you're still around. Well, whatever it's doing, it doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it, right? I didn't include jQuery in the pastebin, because Wordpress loads it for me in the header. The order is as follows: 1) Require.js 2) jQuery 3) BlockUI. It should be working fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/7NDQt/ Check the "Manage Resources" tab at the left and you'll see the script loaded in the correct order. Then check the console. POW! Not very fun... *Edit:* Also worth mentioning the jQuery version doesn't matter, i'm running 1.8 on my site and 1.9 on the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should define jquery as a shim as following:

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$'
    }
  },
  path : {
    jquery : '$PATH/jquery.js'
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the path for though, and what does shim actually do?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the data-main attribute to load a main.js file with require.js:

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
```

where the main.js file is a flavour of:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {         // regard the shim structure as a dependency map
        'jquery': [],
        'app': ['jquery']    // app code will not execute before jquery is loaded
    },
    waitSeconds: 20
});

require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'app'
    ],
    function(
        $
    ) {
        //the plugins from the dependency array have been loaded.
        console.log ("jQuery and app loaded through require.js");
    }
);
```

The example above assumes that you load jquery.js from the same location as require.js (which is, your site)