# RequireJs asynchron loading, synchrones loading differences between requirejs and require

Tags: requirejs

Good evening,

im new with requireJs and hope my questions are not stupid, its my first :).

1. Why the guy is using in the code above require and requirejs, whats the difference?

   ```
       require(["config"], function(config){
           requirejs.config(config);
           require(["App", "ember"], function(App, Ember){
               var app_name = config.app_name || "App";
               root[app_name] = App = Ember.Application.create(App);
               App.deferUntilDOMReady();
           });
       });
   ```

   1. Is there a differences beetween the different code spellings?
   2. Will the script ressources are loaded asynchon or synchron in both cases?
   3. If i use requirejs-jquery are jquery (the $) than global or only local scope (amd scope)?

   ```
       require(['script1','script2'], function() {}
   ```

   ```
       require(function(require) {
         require('script1');
         require('script2');
   }
   ```
2. Is it possible to have several require configs?
   For example i have a bunch of nested structures like /modules/helper/example/js/example.
   At the moment i have all required shims,paths                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             inside the main.js config. 
   I want to place a main.js or config.js inside each helper module, which configer the required shims, pathes, etc.

Than i no longer need places all configs, pathes inside the main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.1
RequireJS registers **TWO** instances of itself in global scope - `require` and `requirejs` - really just for one reason - if one (most likely `require`) is overriden with another `require` that is different in scope or implementation, you still have `requirejs` - usually always a global. This separation is important when you plan to consume resources that are relative to the module you are in now.

```
// contents of 'a/b/c.js' module file
define(['require'], function(require){

    // "local scope" require call
    // resolves to 'a/b/d.js' file
    require(['./d'], function(d){})

    // "global scope" require call
    // resolves to 'd.js' file
    requirejs(['./d'], function(d){})
})
```

Note that asking for local require only makes sense in **define** calls. As `define` call is what establishes the "module" and it's ID. The above is equivalent to this **named** define:

```
// contents of whatever file
define('a/b/c', ['require'], function(require){

    // "local scope" require call
    // resolves to 'a/b/d.js' file
    require(['./d'], function(d){})

    // "global scope" require call
    // resolves to 'd.js' file
    requirejs(['./d'], function(d){})
})
```

The other, secret, reason why James put `requirejs` in there is to force you to keep using `require` in local scope because his build tool looks for that specific string `require` to find the require calls. You do this, and `r.js` suddenly cannot follow you dependency tree because `myLocalRequire` is not what `r.js` expects:

```
// contents of 'a/b/c.js' module file
define(['require'], function(myLocalRequire){

    // "local scope" require call
    // resolves to 'a/b/d.js' file
    myLocalRequire(['./d'], function(d){})

    // "global scope" require call
    // resolves to 'd.js' file
    require(['./d'], function(d){})
})
```

1.2 RequireJS does **NOT** do sync loading at all. The only place where you think that "it must be sync!" - the CommonJS style call like `var a = require('a')` it's still not. It yanks the resource out of cache. In other words, it never **loads** anything sync.

1.3 Don't use bundled RequireJS+jQuery. It makes an already huge jQuery more huge and interferes with browser cache. (Instead of using cached jQuery from CDN you force user to download same jQuery again - 100k of trash).

See this instead: [Use jQuery as a dependency without loading jQuery with RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854046/use-jquery-as-a-dependency-without-loading-jquery-with-requirejs/)

2.0 Don't. separate configs is a trap. It's hell that you willingly enter once you start "building" your apps. I dare you to give me one example of a separate sane config that I cannot express as either named defines group or "packages" where main module loads relative resource.

The only thing that must be in your RequireJS config is 'baseUrl' and 2-5 globally-used 'paths' definitions. That's it.