# Benefits of using jQuery (or underscore) with a script-loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, underscore.js, amd

There are discussions about AMD-support for jQuery and underscore. Many questions here show, that developers have problems using these libraries with require or curl. Why not using jQuery and underscore "as they are" (with their own script-element)? Why not using module-systems like require just for the actual app-code?

Comment: I'm not that confident with AMD, but my guess is that if you use AMD with jQuery etc you can create release builds which creates just a single JS file from various modules. At least that was my understanding of http://requirejs.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the benefits of using, for example RequireJS, is the ability to minify and optimize everything into **one file**, making the load size smaller and fewer requests.

Many blindly focus on the size of their files and forget that the amount of files also is important - because you need to do a request for each file. The fewer requests the client have to do the better.

I would look into the r.js in RequireJS to learn more about optimization.

---

#### To answer your question:

Adding jQuery and underscore separately would increase load size for the client and it would also add two request, which is not optimal.

jQuery should not be an issue to add to RequireJS anymore, you do not need to shim or anything like that. If you do want underscore you should use LoDash instead, which supports AMD, and is a performance optimized version of underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Another use-case that we run into at my workplace is when you are embedding your app into someone else's site. The parent site probably already has their own jQuery code running on the page. Their jQuery code may be a different version than yours, it may use different plugins than you do, etc. So having your own version of jQuery and not leaking it to the global scope is a huge win in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First:

AMD-style loaders solve only one problem - you can avoid having all of your code in one file during development. The problem is solved only when you "build" the AMD tree at the end. If you don't you end up with more HTTP requests.

So, when you choose the way, think about AMD as "module loader API + compiler / assembler" package.

Although I personally largely prefer CurlJS, I must say having `r.js` is a big selling point for RequireJS.

This means that if you can build with something else but `r.js` (CurlJS has a **beta** build script. I have an AMD build script http://prunejs.com/ Lot's of other people prefer their own build scripts) go with CurlJS. Else go with RequireJS.

Second:
jQuery, Underscore etc.

These have no influence whatsoever on your AMD choices. They can continue to be global and used as such. jQuery even helps you (in a screwed up way though) by registering itself as AMD module when it sees AMD system loaded:

[Use jQuery as a dependency without loading jQuery with RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854046/use-jquery-as-a-dependency-without-loading-jquery-with-requirejs/14870365?noredirect=1#comment20961466_14870365)

You can continue to load Underscore through script tags, but create a fake / wrapper AMD module for it:

```
define('underscore', function(){
    return window._
});
```

In other words, AMD system may piggy-back on top of your present inline script tags structure